# how to use schema.org metadata on a review for multiple ratings?

Tags: metadata, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I need to markup the review metadata for a product, but the review will have multiple ratings like service, satisfaction, quality, lifetime etc in the original schema.org documentation for review (http://schema.org/Review) there is only property/field: `reviewRating` using this i can only use it for one field but i need to provide metadata for all the fields, is there a solution for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually one property isn't an issue here since it can be used multiple times. There were a lot of discussions around cardinality of schema.org properties. You can dive into details [here](http://www.w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/5) (issue at open tracker) and [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Singularity) (W3C Wiki page).

I personally follow the rule stated by Guha:

> Right now, it is always allowed to have multiple values.

Another part of your question is how to describe *different* ratings. You can use mechanism of   "multiple inheritance" like in "serious" programming language. That is one entity may have several types. In your case one type will be http://schema.org/Rating and another (quality, service, etc) you can get from any external to schema.org vocabulary. E.g., [productontology](http://www.productontology.org) is a good candidate (you can use http://www.productontology.org/id/Quality_philosophy, http://www.productontology.org/id/Customer_service accordingly). With RDFA you can just go with it - language itself provides all the necessary mechanisms to say that. But for microdata (and I bet you're using this one) you need to do "dirty hack" and use *additionalType* property.

So simple example of what you need is smth like this:

```
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <span itemprop="name">Not a happy camper</span> -
    by <span itemprop="author">Ellie</span>,
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-04-01">April 1, 2011
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="additionalType" content="http://www.productontology.org/id/Quality_philosophy">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">1</span>/
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>stars
    </div>
        <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="additionalType" content="http://www.productontology.org/id/Customer_service">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>/
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>stars
    </div>
    <span itemprop="description">The lamp burned out and now I have to replace
    it. </span>
  </div>
```

And Google validator [sees](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e4b7a4f6a8c6d355666d2c862a03) all the data.